# Need only numbers and not Name resolution with Source Port in Wireshark

Tags: port, wireshark

Using wireshark to display packet information, I get name resolved Source and Destination Port ->

```
1   0.000000    121.14.142.72   0.32.59.21  TCP 62  ms-wbt-server   48983
```

where the last two values-> ms-wbt-server and 48983 are Source Port and Destination Ports. I instead only want to see port number and not the Name Resolution.

Does anyone know if this setting is even possible in Wireshark?

Comment: Disable name resolution for transport layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of doing that.

The first is to completely turn off transport-layer name resolution.  That's View -> Name Resolution -> Enable for Transport Layer in the GTK+ version and View -> Name Resolution -> Resolve Transport Layer in the Qt version; if it's checked, select it, which will disable (and un-check) it.  That will prevent port numbers from being resolved to names *everywhere* in Wireshark.

The second is to use "Src port (unresolved)" and "Dst port (unresolved)" rather than "Source port" and "Destination port" for the port number column.  That will only affect the column display, which is what you're showing in your example above.

Comment: Thanks. The second one worked for me. Wasted so many hours of the day today in figuring this one out before heading to this forum!